# Getting problems with deprecated code after upgrading BloC to 8.0.0 ( in flutter )

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, bloc

Folks, I'm new too flutter.
I was working on a project that started giving me problems after an automatic upgrade to BloC 8.0.0.

Apparently some features got deprecated in the new version.

I'm getting this message:

'transformEvents' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use `on<Event>` with an `EventTransformer` instead. Will be removed in v8.0.0.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.dartdeprecated_member_use
(deprecated) Stream<Transition<SearchEvent, SearchState>> transformEvents(Stream events, Stream<Transition<SearchEvent, SearchState>> Function(SearchEvent) transitionFn)
package:bloc/src/bloc.dart

Can you please let me know how do I fix this?

Comment: Take a look the migration guide: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration especially https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%e2%9c%a8-introduce-new-onlteventgt-api

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out